# Simple way to count emails in GMail thread

Tags: email, gmail, imap

Is there any simple way to know how many emails are in thread in GMail mailbox? I fetched information about a message (message_id, X-GM-THRID, references, in_reply_to etc) and I want to know how many other messages with same X-GM-THRID are in the mailbox. Is it possible without fetching information about those other messages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this page about GMail IMAP extensions](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap_extensions#access_to_the_gmail_thread_id_x-gm-thrid), `X-GM-THRID` is supported as a search key.  This is the example from that page:

```
a009 UID SEARCH X-GM-THRID 1266894439832287888
* SEARCH 2 3 4
a009 OK Search (Success)
```

That gives you the UIDs of the messages in that thread, and you can just count the number of results.

If you really just want the count, and don't need the message ids, you can make use of the fact that GMail supports the `ESEARCH` capability (described in [RFC 4731](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4731)), which lets you ask for the count and nothing else:

```
C: 202 SEARCH RETURN (COUNT) X-GM-THRID 1261978514042297166
S: * ESEARCH (TAG "202") COUNT 2
S: 202 OK SEARCH completed (Success)
```

Comment: Strange to see someone answer an IMAP question concisely, correctly and helpfully. Chapeau.

Comment: Wow how was it simple! Thanks a lot, your answer is a great help!

Comment: @arnt we don't often have precise questions.

Comment: True, we don't. But to see a good, correct, etc answer from someone other than the usual suspects! It quite charmed me.